# CNN: what if change some convolution layers with others

Tags: conv-neural-network, convolution

Generally at the end of CNN there is a linear(fully connected layer) layers. But I have recently thought what if i change some convolution layers in CNN with linear layers? Is it useful? if yes where? or if no why not? I would really like to listen your opinion.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am sorry "Mr.Bot" You may not understand curiosity but Human can be intrigued by imagination. How can i clarify more? What happened if some convolution layers are replaced by fully connected layers? It can increase the performance?